# Using Ajax / jQuery to change div content on local application (intranet)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, intranet

Is it possible to use Ajax / jQuery to load  content on a local application (intranet)?

I'm thinking navigation div + changeable content div (multiple content html's).

Since I'm a beginner, this might seem like a stupid question but I appreciate all answers!

Regards
//Albin

Answer (score 3):

it is possible to change content of div or any other element (that is the purpose of AJAX anyway).. you can try using jQuery

$('div').load('url');

the content of the URL is loaded into the div...

Answer (score 0):

sure it is possible, because you just download jquery.js (script, whichs is framework). So you can make all needed changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, the url can be a local relative or absolute one, it doesn't have to include a domain.